# C++ WinHTTP, can't get this to work

Tags: c++, linker-errors, winhttp, winhttprequest

I want to use WinHTTP to do some HTTP requests. Really basic stuff, but WinHTTP seems to be kind of complex compared to what I actually just want to do.
Well, I couldn't even get this example code from the msdn to work:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#code-snippet-1

What I tried is the following:
I created a new win32 console app with precomp header in VC++ 2010.
I added these includes:

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <winhttp.h>
```

and put the example code in the _tmain function.

When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
WinHttpTestings.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__[FUNCTIONNAME]@4 referenced in function _wmain
```

For every WinHttp function called.

I hope you can help me out, sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to bind some lib to your project.

Comment: A whole lib? Or do you mean a header file include?

Comment: Yes, aparently, `winhttp.lib`, it has to be associated with your project in order to compile. You can do it by adding it to your linker settings or by adding `#pragma comment(lib, winhttp.lib)` to your headers.

Comment: Looks like it worked! Thank you! winhttp.lib needed to be in quotes though.  
You should add it as real answer. :)